# Disable only specific list items in a win32 ListView

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

I am using win32, c++.
I have a ListView & i want to disable (grey out) only some of the items from the list.
Is that possible or only whole ListView can be greyed out?

Answer (score 0):

The ListView control does not have a concept of disabled items. You can simulate that appearance using custom drawing support. This [Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff919573(v=vs.85).aspx) demonstrates how to change the text and background color of items within the list view.

You would need to go further and provide some means of determining when a disabled item is selected within the view (as the selection will continue to work).

Answer (score 0):

The Windows List View Common Control does not have a disabled state for Items. If you want to do that, you will have to implement it yourself.

This is a not-trivial exercise. It's not hard to change the visible appearance using customer draw, but handling hit-testing and selection would be quite complex.